# Best way to reload a ReactJS component to read from localStorage

Tags: reactjs

Context: I have a `<Header />` component that has a button which redirects the user to a `<SignIn />` component. The  `<Header />` component is always displayed, however when the user is signed in, the Login button disappears and replaced by the user's name.

I will not go in detail about the authentication mechanism, but let's just say it is based on a JWT that is stored in localStorage. I have the following piece of code in `<Header />` in order to read the cookie and determine whether to show the login button or not:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
      this.props.fetchUser();
    }
  }
...
```

However this only works on a browser refresh or if I use the native JS window.reload(). If I use react router redirections, the Login button in the `<Header />` component is not refreshed and still displays (although the cookie is set).

I am wondering what is the best practice, and avoiding the whole page refresh...

Comment: Can you show your `render` method?

Comment: You could pass a function from your parent component to your login component as a prop. When logged in and after you set your localStorage, call the parent function `reloadTokenFromLocalStorage` (or whatever you want to call it). If the token is there,update the Header prop token (which will reload the Header component)

Comment: @mokk can you point to an example? I like this kind of flow. I assume you're suggesting ComponentWillReceiveProps() lifecycle method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is super pseudo code, but hopefully that would be enough :)

```
class App {
  const handleLoggedIn = () => {
    const token = readFromLocalStorage()
    if (token) {
      this.setState({token})
    }
  }
  <Header token={this.state.token} />
  <Login onLogin={this.handleLoggedIn}
}

class Login {
  // After loging in and setting your token to your local storage:
  this.props.onLogin()
}

class Header {
  if (this.props.token)
    <User />
  else
    <Login />
}
```

So once you are logged in and set your token to the local storage, you just call the parent function handleLoggedIn which will try to retrieve the token from your local storage. If it is set, it will re-set it as your App state, which will refresh your Header component as one of its props has been updated

(But that mainly depends on how you've implemented the rest of your code and how easily you can access the parent function from your login flow as pointed by Dubes)

Answer (score 0):

Two possible scenarios I can think of:

**Scenario 1** 
You've someway of hooking into the flow when user signs in. For e.x. maybe your auth system is setting a success flag in header/query or perhaps the component which writes the jwt to the localstorage is in your control/tree.

In that case, you should be derive that information and be able to set a prop which your header component can use.

**Scenario 2**

You don't have any way of hooking into your auth workflow and can only read the localstorage item. For e.x. a user has signed on with SSO and you want to reflect that without having to refresh the entire page.

I think you can use a `setInterval` to read the state of the cookie and set a state in your header component. As long as you are not doing intensive calculations in your setInterval code, it should not be an overhead. Do remember to clearInterval on unmount.

Take a look at [this example](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) in official docs for inspriration.